# Sine square in python

Tags: python, trigonometry

Need help. How I can get sine square in python? Is there specific method or function?

[image]

Some supposedly obvious solutions are NOT suitable. Examples:

```
import numpy as np
import math


x = np.arange(0, 3, 0.5)
print([(math.sin(i) ** 2) for i in x])
print([math.sin(math.sin(i))for i in x])
# [0.0, 0.22984884706593015, 0.7080734182735712, 0.9949962483002227, 0.826821810431806, 0.3581689072683868]
#[0.0, 0.4612695550331807, 0.7456241416655579, 0.8401148815567654, 0.7890723435728884, 0.5633808209655248]

# or

x = np.arange(0, 3, 0.5)
print(np.sin(x) ** 2)
print(np.sin(np.sin(x)))
# [0.         0.22984885 0.70807342 0.99499625 0.82682181 0.35816891]
# [0.         0.46126956 0.74562414 0.84011488 0.78907234 0.56338082]
```

Comment: What's wrong with `math.sin(x) ** 2`?

Comment: Dosn't work! Check uorself:

x = np.arange(0, 3, 0.5)
print([(math.sin(i) ** 2) for i in x])
print([math.sin(math.sin(i))for i in x])

Comment: Are you considering sin(sin(x)) == sin(x) ** 2? If so, it is not!

Comment: `math.sin(x) ** 2` is _fine_ - just make sure your inputs are RADIANS, e.g. `math.sin(math.radians(x))`

Answer (score 5):

You need to look for [math](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) module in Python. See [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.sin).

```
math.sin(x) ** 2
```

You can also use `math.pow(x,y)`. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/math.html#math.pow) for how to raise a number x raised to the power y.

A small example program.

```
import math
rad = int(input("Enter radians: "))
print(math.sin(rad) ** 2)
```

If you want to convert from radians to degrees or vice-versa, have a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/math.html#angular-conversion).

Comment: It's wrong decision. you can check it yourself: 

import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 3, 0.5)
print(np.sin(x) ** 2)
print(np.sin(np.sin(x)))

Comment: Can you post your code in the question?

Comment: Can you post current output and desired output with your code?

Comment: Does `x` stores the values as degress or radians?

Answer (score 0):

You will be safer if you use it as follows -

```
((math.sin(x)) ** 2)
```

Emphasis is to put the math.sin(x) inside bracket.

Comment: bracket is not required. Because `math.sin(x)` will be evaluated first with or without brackets. After that squaring operation will occur.

Comment: Ok, I appereciate you but, I have said that we will be on safer side by using that.

Comment: x = np.arange(0, 3, 0.5)

print([(math.sin(i) ** 2) for i in x])

print([math.sin(math.sin(i))for i in x])

It doesn't work

Comment: I've upgrade own question, added code